# In python, how can i get the multiplication of array elements using recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I want to get the multiplication of array elements using recursion.

**arr** is array, and **n** is length of the array.

if arr=[1, 2, 3], n=3, answer is 6.

I tried this, but error occurred.

```
def multiply(arr, n):
    if n == 0:
        return arr
    else:
        return arr[n] * \
               multyply(arr[n - 1])
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is close. Try change `n` to count up and the exit condition to check when `n` exceeds the length of `arr` -

```py
def multiply(arr, n = 0):
  if n >= len(arr):
    return 1
  else:
    return arr[n] * multiply(arr, n + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement it like this

```
def mul(arr):
    if not arr:
        return 1
    return arr[0] * mul(arr[1:])
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. How do I derive it using the length of the list, n?